How can I measure the speed of sound with an oscilloscope and ultrasonic sensor? (Currently getting low value.)
I have taken the ultrasonic pair (Only the silver components that resemble microphones) from an HC-SR04  sensor and attached directly them to an oscilloscope/signal generator with a ~11.5cm gap between the sensors in an attempt to measure the speed of sound.
According to the scope, I'm getting around 200m/s measuring from the start of the signal generator to the start of sine wave on the receptor. The pair is held in place so the distance between them is constant, successive measurements give me a range from 190 to 210 m/s but I am not the most accurate with the scopes cursors.
What needs to be done to get a value closer to 343 m/s? That should be around 335uS.


Edit: Thanks for the replies. The best I got comparing similar points in the waves of two different receptors with different distances was around 333 m/s which seems close enough but I was generous with cursor position. The amplitude on the receiver signal drops drastically with greater distances and broader angles between the pair (I've used 5Vpp max with a square wave, which is similar to the signal on the module). The HC-SR04 that I have seems to generate 8 pulses instead of the six found on random pdfs and articles online.
In case someone ends up here in the future I also added images of wave bursts and the response on the setup with the 11.5 cm gap, yellow wave on the emitter and green wave on the receiver. It still seems slow when estimating time from the last pulse to the peak voltage on the receptor instead of the beginning of both waveforms.





hint: your question should be asking how to measure the speed of sound with oscilloscope and two ultrasonic sensors?

how do you know when the emitter begins outputting sound?

@jsotola From the green flatline at the beginning of the screen, I'm physically making the connection on the signal generator with the trigger setup on the scope

read my question again

it's μs, not uS. one is microseconds, the other is u-Siemens.

take two measurements ... one at some arbitrary distance and again at a known distance from the first measurement... then calculate the difference between the two measurements

Use something as 8-10 pulses at emission, repeat every ms ( or more).

Use two ultrasonic microphones, one near to the speaker and one far away, then the speaker doesn't really matter.  Make sure both mics have a clear line-of-sight to the speaker of course.  Then measure the two mic signals and factor in the distance between the two mics.

Hint:  The bigger the gap you use, the less impact any accumulated errors will have on your calculation.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a bout Physics, not electrical

Your approach is not taking into account the very narrow bandwidth of the transducers. @jsotola's point is that it takes some time for the oscillations to build up in the transmitter, and a similar time for the receiver to react to the energy that it receives.
You need to come up with an approach that is not affected by these effects. For example, a correlation measurement between two receivers at different distances would yield the kind of data you're looking for.
Alternatively, simply using a much longer distance between the transducers would make the error due to the limited rise time a smaller fraction of the total time.

Thanks, I've now tried measuring directly on a working HC-SR04 but must have done something wrong with the scope because I was getting instant speed. Using a second receptor at a different know distance is a great idea, I'll try that and update later.

@TalkoAcc Using Dave's method will allow you to do a correlation between the two received signals giving you a very accurate time difference. You can do a mathematical correlation in a program (save the oscilloscope numeric data to a file) or you can graphically do this in a graphing program. You should be able to use a pulse width of 5 to 10 ms, assuming the Q of the transducers is similar.


how to measure the speed of sound with oscilloscope and ultrasonic
sensor? (Currently getting low value)

Time is required for these narrow-bandwidth transducers to build amplitude to full - both transmitter and receiver. This slow rise time of the waveform envelope makes time measurements difficult.
For measuring speed-of-sound, a different measurement method can be used...one that doesn't rely on a slow rise-to-full amplitude...

Excite the transmitter with continuous 40 kHz sine or square (doesn't matter). It is important that you know the frequency exactly.
The receiver will show a 40 kHz sine wave, whose amplitude will slowly change with distance. We're not interested in amplitude, but phase. As you move the receiver to a new distance, phase will scan through many cycles.

Since one cycle of 40 kHz in air having 340 m/s propagation speed, each cycle on your 'scope represents 340/40000 or 8.5 mm.

Trigger your 'scope from the function generator that excites the transmitter.

Observe the sinewave of the receiver, and count cycles as they pass by when you move it to a new position. To do this, 'scope time scale should be roughly 5 microseconds/cm.


Nice! This would make a good science-fair project. It should be easy to get <0.1% error with this method.

You can reduce one of the sources of error by having the transmitter connected to the signal generator continuously, and putting a fan or something else with a rotating vane in the signal path.  This should create pulses of audio at the receiver with more sharply defined starting and stopping.
A light beam detector can be positioned around the fan to produce a trigger pulse as a blade goes by.  With correct positioning, the leading edge of the trigger pulse with be synchronized with the point in time when the audio beam becomes unblocked by a fan blade.
Actually, I think this is a good idea for a high school science fair project.

Calibrate your system with zero distance, then see what changes when you go further away
